# Can I install OS X Snow Leopard on 2006 mac mini?

Tags: macos, mac-mini

So..I bought my first macbook pro few days ago, but found I don't need a laptop. I figured out that I can buy used mac mini + windows laptop for my developer environment.

is it possible to install snow leopard on a 2006 mac mini?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is. [See here](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/stats/mac_mini_cs_1.5.html).

As long as it is an Intel Mac Mini (with a minumum of 1gb ram) you'll be fine.

If its a Power PC Mac Mini then you'll only be able to install Leopard (not Snow Leopard)

Comment: Qualification: it'll need to be upgraded to 1GB of RAM for Snow Leopard (that model shipped with only 512MB by default).